# Set of formulas in Model Theory

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

I'm reading the book Model Theory by Chang and Keisler and there is one thing that always bugs me. Very frequently we have something like $\Sigma(x)$ representing the set of all formulas in a language that have x free, but what does it mean for a set to contain a formula?

The closest I've been able to get to a sensible answer would be to represent each formula by something like $\{x \in A : \psi(x)\}$ (i.e. the set of all elements of the universe of a model that satisfy the formula), but then how would you represent formulas without free variables? That is, suppose I have the sequence of formulas $0 \neq S0$, $0 \neq SS0$, $0 \neq SSS0$ and so on. They are all true of every model of Peano Arithmetic, but how would I build a set that contained these formulas? What does it even mean to have a set contain them?

Comment: Formulas are strings of characters. Just like theories are sets of strings of characters that happen to be closed formulas. There are a number of ways to instantiate syntax in a strong enough theory; that's what Godel's proof relied on to begin with.

Comment: Yes, I know, but in the book they don't mention Gödel numbering nor do they say that the formulas are encoded anywhere. Also, the theory _isn't_ supposed to be strong enough, we're supposed to be able to make these sets with formulas of whatever language/theory, even if it's only a finite theory of equality.

Comment: Chances are they don't mention their coding because it's totally irrelevant for most applications? It would be needlessly fussy to belabor an encoding or two and go "but this won't have much bearing on the discussions in this book".

Comment: That doesn't really go with the rest of the book. They have had passages that went explicitly "This is trivial but we'll show it anyway." and even the parts they _didn't_ show they mentioned "We're not showing how but we're doing this." So no, chances are they really really didn't do that. Furthermore, that still doesn't address the second point which is that they make sets of formulas of every theory they discuss, not just Peano-strong theories, so how would they encode those formulas when you can have a model whose universe has a grand total of three symbols?

Comment: Your second point doesn't really make sense. I haven't suggested, nor do I intend to suggest, that they encode a language with only three symbols. Rather, you can choose ways of encoding that make it easy to toss in new signs as wanted (e.g. finite sequences over an alphabet that always at least includes the alphabet of FoL). I don't know what kind of answer you're looking for here, but I suggest you ask Chang or Keisler if you want to know what they mean.

Comment: The point is that to encode the formula, you need to encode it in something (i.e. numbers), but when these numbers _aren't there_ to begin with, you can't use them to encode anything. You're supposed to be able to for instance create a set of all the formulas with $0 \leq n \leq 3$ variables over the language $\{\leq, x_0, x_1, x_2, c_0, c_1, c_2\}$ without using numbers to encode these formulas because you don't have access to them. How do you encode formulas when you don't have Peano Arithmetic or anything as strong to back you up? (But it seems the answer below covers this.)

Comment: What do you mean "don't have access to them"? Any set theory you'd want to work in will have numbers, a great many of them. There seems to be a very bad confusion of theory and metatheory here...

Comment: Right, it's because I had missed the "Model Theory is built in and on Set Theory" bit.

Comment: Ah! That would make matters confusing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Model theory is rarely done in a system which is inadequate for talking about sets to begin with. Often the choice of theory is $\sf ZFC$ or a stronger theory (e.g. $\sf ZFC$ with the addition of large cardinals, or some axiom deciding the continuum function).

In this context, then, a language is a set, and the formulas are finite strings from that alphabet. Note that the fact that we can define when a string is a WFF is exactly the reason why there is a set of all the formulas. Now we can define the predicate which tells us whether or not $x$ is a free variable in a formula.

And that's it, we define the set $\Sigma(x)$ as all those formulas satisfying that predicate.

Alternatively, we can talk about logic and basic model theory in $\sf PA$, or extensions thereof, where we can recursively encode formulas and define the above predicate. Although in that context the set of formulas doesn't exist as above, because it is not an element of the universe (which is a model of $\sf PA$, so the universe contains integers and not sets). But in that case we talk about recursive definitions, and indeed $\Sigma(x)$ is a recursive set.

In either case the meaning of that set is that however we chose to represent the notion of "formula", we could have defined a collection (either a set, or some nicely definable collection of integers) which is interpreted to be exactly those formula in which $x$ is a free variable. This set, or whatever, exists in the meta-theory, and not in the universe of the model.

Comment: And with this dies my tablet, leaving me without a computer or internet access until the stupid blackout ends. Hopefully during the night... I hope to read any comments or follow ups when I wake up. In the meantime, if anyone sees a typo or a minor mistake don't hesitate to correct it, and don't be wary about answering questions from the comments either. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, so if you have Model Theory built around (say) ZFC then these sets of formulas are nothing more than sets of strings of the elements of the language? That... sounds pretty awful and quirky but if it's the only way... From the beginning of the book it's been bothering me, how they make definitions and theorems that depend on these sets of formulas.

Comment: First of all, built in and on set theory, not around it. But more importantly why doesn't it bother you when someone is taking sets of real numbers? sequences of continuous functions? and so on and so forth?

Comment: This is IMO something which is not stressed enough in introductory texts to math. logic. You need *some* math. logic to formulate what ZFC (or some other theory) is and what is a correct proof in it. But most of the math. logic is then built inside some set theory which one takes for granted. So if one would like to establish these things "from the scratch" (i.e. from some "finitary" set meta-theory), one should say (provide metadefinitions) of what is a wff, theory, proof, then formulate say ZFC and then inside ZFC one can define wffs and other stuff again. At least I understand it this way.

Comment: I have no idea why that doesn't bother me, now that I think of it. The answer that my brain gave me when prodded was "because real numbers aren't standing for anything but themselves" and then I did a double-take and recalled that real numbers are just a set of Dedekind Cuts (well, that's my favourite construction anyway) on a set of equivalence classes of a set of equivalence classes of a set of sets, so... yeah, I guess I should self-modify this away.

Comment: (Although intuitively I'm still bothered, there's a difference between using a bunch of sets built on Logic and then calling them "numbers" and using a bunch of sets built on Logic to represent Logic itself.)

Comment: @Pavel: You can easily formulate $\sf ZFC$ and everything else in $\sf PA$, or some other theory strong enough to interpret first-order logic and basic facts about proofs and provability. Then when working inside $\sf ZFC$ you can translate everything to proofs from $\sf ZFC$ in that finitary meta-theory. Of course one would have to justify that meta-theory, and so on. But it is easily done.